# javax.comm and how to fix java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, eclipse, java-me, serial-port, midp

I'm creating a midlet for a mobile. This midlet is accessing the com4 port. I already added the javax.comm to jre1.6.0, jre6 and jdk1.6.0 folders (in lib\ext).

I also have the javax.comm.jar in a folder named lib in my project folder and referenced it in build path.

os: windows 7.
mobile: china mobile.
IDE: eclipse with eclipseME1.8 installed.

when I run the project in eclipse it's giving me this error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: MainMidlet: javax/comm/SerialPortEventListener 
    at com.sun.midp.midlet.MIDletState.createMIDlet(+29)
    at com.sun.midp.midlet.Scheduler.schedule(+52)
    at com.sun.midp.main.Main.runLocalClass(+28)
    at com.sun.midp.main.Main.main(+80)
```

I know that the javax.comm will not work on 64x windows, but why when I install the jar in the device it doesn't work? no error message either just this: "the jar file is terminated."
So I went to google and searched for answer and found txrx for windows x86 and x64 but I don't know if this is working for a Midlet in a mobile device. Since they have been provided that for windows. So how do I get around this? here is the midlet class code just for the record:

```
import javax.microedition.lcdui.*;
import javax.microedition.midlet.MIDlet;
import javax.microedition.midlet.MIDletStateChangeException;
import javax.comm.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class MainMidlet extends MIDlet implements CommandListener,
    SerialPortEventListener {
// displaying this midlet
private Display display;
private Form form;
private StringItem stringItem;
private Command exitCommand;
// serial vars
private CommPortIdentifier portId;
private Enumeration portList;
private InputStream inputStream;
private SerialPort serialPort;
private Thread readThread;

public MainMidlet() {
    portList = CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifiers();
    while (portList.hasMoreElements()) {
        portId = (CommPortIdentifier) portList.nextElement();
        if (portId.getPortType() == CommPortIdentifier.PORT_SERIAL) {
            if (portId.getName().equals("COM4")) {
                this.AttachToCom();
            }
        }
    }
}

protected void destroyApp(boolean arg0) throws MIDletStateChangeException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

protected void pauseApp() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

public void commandAction(Command command, Displayable displayable) {
    if (displayable == form) {
        if (command == exitCommand) {
            exitMIDlet();
        }
    }
}

public void startApp() {
    stringItem = new StringItem("Hello", "Serial app is running!");
    form = new Form(null, new Item[] { stringItem });
    exitCommand = new Command("Exit", Command.EXIT, 1);
    form.addCommand(exitCommand);
    form.setCommandListener(this);
    display = Display.getDisplay(this);
    display.setCurrent(form);
}

public void exitMIDlet() {
    display.setCurrent(null);
    notifyDestroyed();
}

public void serialEvent(SerialPortEvent ev) {
    print("serialEvent is called.");
    switch (ev.getEventType()) {
    case SerialPortEvent.BI:
    case SerialPortEvent.OE:
    case SerialPortEvent.FE:
    case SerialPortEvent.PE:
    case SerialPortEvent.CD:
    case SerialPortEvent.CTS:
    case SerialPortEvent.DSR:
    case SerialPortEvent.RI:
    case SerialPortEvent.OUTPUT_BUFFER_EMPTY:
        break;
    case SerialPortEvent.DATA_AVAILABLE:
        byte[] readBuffer = new byte[20];
        try {
            while (inputStream.available() > 0) {
                inputStream.read(readBuffer);
            }
            print(new String(readBuffer));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            print(e.getMessage());
        }
        break;
    }
}

private void AttachToCom() {
    try {
        serialPort = (SerialPort) portId.open("MyProject", 2000);
    } catch (PortInUseException e) {
        print(e.getMessage());
    }
    try {
        inputStream = serialPort.getInputStream();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        print(e.getMessage());
    }
    try {
        serialPort.addEventListener(this);
    } catch (TooManyListenersException e) {
        print(e.getMessage());
    }
    serialPort.notifyOnDataAvailable(true);
    try {
        serialPort.setSerialPortParams(9600, SerialPort.DATABITS_8,
                SerialPort.STOPBITS_1, SerialPort.PARITY_NONE);
    } catch (UnsupportedCommOperationException e) {
        print(e.getMessage());
    }
    readThread = new Thread((Runnable) this);
    readThread.start();
}

private void print(String str) {
    form.append(str + "\r\n");
}
    }
```

There is also one more thing, the interface SerialPortEventListener inherits from java.util.EventListener which my java.util package doesn't have. Basically I added whatever my java.util and java.io don't have to the src folder and each in a separate file (and package). Here they are:

```
//the file is named EventListener.java and in a package named java.util
package java.util;
/**
* A tagging interface that all event listener interfaces must extend.
* @since JDK1.1
*/
public interface EventListener {
} 

//the file is named EventObject.java and in a package named java.util
//removed the comment to minimize this post
package java.util;

// removed the comment to minimize this post
public class EventObject implements java.io.Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 5516075349620653480L;

// The object on which the Event initially occurred.
protected transient Object source;

// removed the comment to minimize this post
public EventObject(Object source) {
    if (source == null)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("null source");

    this.source = source;
}
// removed the comment to minimize this post
public Object getSource() {
    return source;
}
public String toString() {
    return getClass().getName() + "[source=" + source + "]";
}
}
// the file is named TooManyEventListenersException.java and in a package named java.util
// removed comment to reduce this post size

package java.util;

// removed comment to reduce this post size
public class TooManyListenersException extends Exception {
    // removed comment to reduce this post size
    public TooManyListenersException() {
        super();
    }
    // removed comment to reduce this post size
    public TooManyListenersException(String s) {
        super(s);
    }
}    
// in the file named Serializable.java and in a package java.io
package java.io;
public interface Serializable {
}
```

Comment: thank you for letting me know about this. i didn't notice that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using wrong API at mobile side - that's why you're stuck with all these NoClassDefFoundError messages and other missing stuff in java.util.

At MIDP (JSR 118) devices one should use [javax.microedition.io .CommConnection API](http://docs.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/ref-impl/midp2.0/jsr118/javax/microedition/io/CommConnection.html) to communicate via serial port.

Comment: thanks! just one more thing poped up. the javax.comm doesn't exist in the mobile device. how can i redistribute this library? i've putted the javax.comm in the res folder and set up the build path from there but it seems that this doesn't cause the registration of javax.comm in mobile device.

Comment: @jim you aren't expected to _redistribute_ anything comm in the mobile. CommConnection API is out of the box available on a MIDP 2.0 device. For details, check the JSR 118 specification or [microedition io package API docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/ref-impl/midp2.0/jsr118/javax/microedition/io/package-summary.html), section "Serial Port Communications"

Comment: great! but the System.getProperty("microedition.commports"); is not returning any ports(returns just 0). are there other ways to find the ports?

Comment: @jim is 0 value returned on mobile? On mobile, it may be due to bug in your code or because this device doesn't support comm connection. Did you use emulator to [smoke-test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smoke_testing) your code - it can be configured to simulate comm connection support?

Comment: in emulation my program returns COM1, COM2. but on mobile just 0. and the mobile is supporting com connection since when i plug it to PC it has the com choice which says "Com port". beside i tested the mobile with HyperTerminal after choosing that option and it worked great. also it showed up on COM4 in device manager.

Comment: @jim I see. Device apparently has comm connection on a _native_ level. But there's a chance (MIDP JSR allows that) that this support is not provided for MIDP applications. Looks like this is your case - although to test that, I'd probably try connecting with "COM4" hardcoded, ignoring for a moment what system property says

Comment: comm:0 is the setting. but no data is comming in or out yet using hyperterminal.i used outputStream.write(text.getBytes());. hp not showing anything.

Comment: interesting. So far it looks like support for comm at Java level is missing or quite buggy at your device (as opposed to native support)